# Use "Windows is checking for a solution to the..." for bug reporting or providing help/update to the user?

Tags: windows, bug-tracking, crash

Everybody has seen this window before. It shows up on an unhandled exception or maybe other cases like app hang:

[image]

First, what does it? (It was never useful to me)

Secondly, can I - as a developer - use it in any way? I wondered, if I can register at microsoft and then see all bug reports that were send through this dialog. As this window promises to find a solution: Can I actually provide a solution to my users? Like refering them to a webpage or providing an update?

I know from the android appstore that I can see bugreports of my app, if the users sent them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to sign up to [Windows Error Reporting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg487440.aspx).

Comment: Yes, you can, and in theory, it's a good idea. In practice, it's probably not worth the effort unless your installed base is in the millions.

Comment: @oefe Yes, it seems to require some effort. I have done some further research. I need a certificate that costs at least [99 to 399 USD](http://qa.social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/zh-TW/1295/thread/6a29177c-979b-43bc-90b8-ebceccd5b845) to register at WER. The android store charged me nothing for those things ;) I guess I will use some other, cheaper solution, when I include error reporting in my application.

Comment: @OneWorld Indeed, I believe both Chrome and Firefox for instance have their own error reporting, although I think they sign up to WER anyway to see the reports that their own error reporting doesn't catch.